# Possible to configure Jaeger via application.properties?

Tags: opentracing, jaeger, quarkus

According to https://quarkus.io/guides/opentracing-guide all Jeager configuration is via JVM args (-DJAEGER_ENDPOINT...) but I'd like to use either `application.properties` or `microprofile-config.properties` to configure tracing. I've tried the following but the only config that seems to be picked up by Quarkus is the service-name all other properties are ignored.

> ```
> quarkus.jaeger.service-name=my-service <-this one is working
> quarkus.jaeger.endpoint=http://localhost:14268/api/traces <- seems to be ignored
> quarkus.jaeger.reporter-log-spans=true
> quarkus.jaeger.sampler.type=const
> quarkus.jaeger.sampler.parameter=1
> ```

So, question is if it is possible to configure via config-files or this is not currently supported?

Comment: It is definitely possible to configure the Jaeger properties in `application.properties` or in `microprofile-config.properties`.

Do you have any more details you could share or a reproducer project we could look at?

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/enbohm/quarkus-opentracing

Comment: basically, when I start the application with 'mvn compile quarkus:dev -Djvm.args="-DJAEGER_SAMPLER_TYPE=const -DJAEGER_SAMPLER_PARAM=1 -DJAEGER_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:14268/api/traces" it works. Notice that I have no service-name in the jvm-args, that property seems to be read from application.properties as expected (but all other properties seems to be ignored).

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I will check it out soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While doing `mvnDebug quarkus:dev` (without `jvm.args`) and placing a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/jaeger/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/jaeger/runtime/JaegerDeploymentTemplate.java#L39), I see that you all your params are being passed except `quarkus.jaeger.sampler.parameter` which is wrong.
It should be `quarkus.jaeger.sampler.param`

Comment: Great! I can see now that is is working! Since it did evaluate to false by default, no spans or traces was reported. Big thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Your welcome :)! Please accept the answer as to help future viewers of the issue to know that the solution is correct and they should apply it if they have similar problems :)